# How to seed data with autoincremented ID with EF Core Code First in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have a problem with autogenerating primary key values when using Oracle DB with EF Core and db seed.

Example entity:

```
public class State : IBaseEntity, ILastEdited
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

then in `OnModelCreating` methods I have a data seed for this entity:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<State>().HasData(new[]
        {
            new State{ Id = 1, SomeOtherProeprty = "Some value"},
        });
```

The problem is, when deploying to MS SQL, seeds is done and new entities inserted via application are fine.

When deploying to Oracle DB, when user insets a new row to State entity table for the first time, it crashes on PK violation, after that, it runs fine.

How to ensure Oracle starts autoincrementing with 2?

I have multiple tables with initial db seed, so I need something systematic?
Thank you for any help.